# how to get user enter value in pdf-lib using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I am using pdf-lib library https://pdf-lib.js.org/ in react js to create dynamic pdf. I want to get value entered by user in pdf.

I have already created pdf and saved in database.  I am fetching pdf from database and displaying in react using iFrame. In the pdf, their are textFields in which user can enter its value , I want to get those values entered by the user.

How to get those values using pdf-lib.

If anyone knows the solution Please help.
Thank you.